# Please help me to read schematic

Tags: schematics, thermistor

I am doing repairs on a monitor of mine and I have to replace a thermistor. I cannot quite read the values of the thermistor on the schematic for the monitor. Can someone see the image and help me to understand this?

[image]

Comment: What the heck happened to this sad-excuse-of-a-schematic?

Comment: My guess is it was a result of some software trying to automatically vectorise a scanned image.

Comment: Either that, or it was drawn by a living caveman. On stone.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SCK 103

NTC Thermistor

Zero power resistance = 10 Ohm

Max steady state current = 3A

[Datasheet](https://www.esr.co.uk/manuals/929-XXX.pdf)

[image]